# What programming language is going to use MATLAB programming?

Tags: matlab, python

Is this possible to work with PYTHON or C in MATLAB.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! As you can see, several of our members were confused by what your question is.  Can you rephrase it? And give more detail in the body of the question. Why do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab is its own programming language/environment. It has the ability to use other languages through [MEX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) or can be called through other languages through the [Matlab API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html).

A lot of people are moving to using scipy/numpy in Python from Matlab, since Python is free whereas Matlab costs lots of money.

Comment: Thumbs up for python! Python is also the better programming language in nearly every aspect, and often faster than matlab too. Not to mention the number of libraries that allow you to do just about anything. Lastly, matlab's GUI programming is terrible, whereas python offers a number of GUI framework options for portable applications!